# Google Developer Console publish screenshots for an app

Tags: android, google-play

I don't understand the logic for publishing screenshots in the developer console.
There are 3 sections:
 phone / 7-inch tablet / 10-inch tablet

I prepared screenshots in different sizes for all these 3 sections.

I checked my app in GooglePlay with my 10-inch tablet and all screens are there ( also phone and 7 inch ) . I thought it should only show the pictures depending on the section and not all in sequence.
Also on my phone appears all images. I think this doesn't make sense.

Is there a way to setup the pictures ( upload ) so they only appear on devices depending on the section ?

regards

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.
I've make an account today.
The images are always show in this order.
If you upload screenshots your app is shown in the section "designed for tablets"

Sorry only german statemant:

> Damit Ihre App in der Liste "Speziell für Tablets entwickelt" im Play Store erscheint, müssen Sie mindestens einen Screenshot für ein 7"- und einen Screenshot für ein 10"-Gerät hochladen. Wenn Sie bereits Screenshots hochgeladen haben, verschieben Sie sie unten in den richtigen Bereich.